# Html structure chages when importing content from dev site using wp-cli and wordpress-importer

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli, elementor

I am writing an auto deployment script that deploy themes and user selected plugins on a selected hosting package. the problem i am facing is that when export a WXR file from my dev site it get imported from the wp admin using wordpress importer plugin without any issue, but when i do it using command line the pages get imported but the style and html structure doesn't get imported.

```
/usr/local/bin/wp import %s --authors=skip
```

the %s get replaced with the file name present on the server. The front end editor that in which the entire design is being translated is https://elementor.com/.